# Remove item from view when removed from collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js. I am listen to the "add" event of my collection

```js
this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.addOne);
```

and it will append the view object like this:

```js
addOne: function (as) {
        var v = new XUView({model: as}).render();
        $(v.el).prependTo($('#object-list')).hide().fadeIn().slideDown();
}
```

Now I want to automatically remove objects from the view if the item has been deleted from the collection. I am listening on the "remove" event:

```js
this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.removeOne);
```

And I tried several things for the remove function, but none of them did the job. The removeOne function is triggered correctly, but as I said, without effect. How can I remove the view object from my frontend?

I already tried:

```js
XUView.remove(XUView.where(as));

XUView.remove(as);

this.collection.remove(as);

this.collection.remove(this.collection.where(as));
```

Comment: Where are you calling `this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.removeOne);`?  Specifically, what is `this`?  If it's the view, then you should just be able to call `this.remove()`.  Essentially you need a reference to a view instance, not the view constructor, which is why `XUView.remove()` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a mapping table between your collection and the model views. When the remove event is trigger based on that mapping table you know which element from DOM should be removed or which is the view.

in addOne function you could setp the view on your model

```
addOne: function (as) {
        var v = new XUView({model: as});
        v.render();
        as.view = v;
        $(v.el).prependTo($('#object-list')).hide().fadeIn().slideDown();
}
```

and in remove function

```
removeOne:function(model){
  model.view.remove();
}
```

Comment: Instead of a mere theory why don't you provide some actual code?  http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove simply says "Removes a view from the DOM" -- no need to know which element, the view knows which element, it's the nature of Backbone

Comment: you are right but you have to know which is the view related to your model , i suggest some code in my answer i hope this will help